# Responsive centered image sencha touch carousel

Tags: image, extjs, touch, carousel

I'm creating a dynamic image carousel and I don't know how to make images responsive, properly scaled and centered in the container. I tried with xtype image and with panel with the `<img>` tag in the html.

If I use this configuration

```
{
   xtype: 'image',
   src: 'http://'+i.media
}
```

I get an image fullscreen 100% but on my device (an iPod touch 5th) it appears cropped because the width is more than the screen's

If I use this

```
{
   style: 'text-align:center',
   html: '<img style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%" src="http://'+i.media+'" />'
}
```

I get an image properly scaled and horizontally centered, but vertically aligned on top

Comment: add vertical align: middle  css property

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the result adding background-size:100% to my first example